# writing the outcome of a nested loop to a vector object in R

Tags: r, loops, statistics, nested

I have the following data read into R as a data frame named "data_old":

```
   yes year month
1  15 2004     5
2   9 2005     6
3  15 2006     3
4  12 2004     5
5  14 2005     1
6  15 2006     7
.   .  ...     .
.   .  ...     .
```

I have written a small loop which goes through the data and sums up the yes variable for each month/year combination:

```
year_f <- c(2004:2006)
month_f <- c(1:12)

for (i in year_f){
    for (j in month_f){
        x <- subset(data_old, month == j & year == i, select="yes")
        if (nrow(x) > 0){
            print(sum(x))
            }
        else{print("Nothing")}
        }
    }
```

My question is this: I can print the sum for each month/year combination in the terminal, but how do i store it in a vector? (the nested loop is giving me headaches trying to figure this out).

Thomas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way,

```
library(plyr)
ddply(data_old,.(year,month),function(x) sum(x[1]))

  year month V1
1 2004     5 27
2 2005     1 14
3 2005     6  9
4 2006     3 15
5 2006     7 15
```

Comment: or `ddply(data_old,.(year,month),summarize, yes = sum(yes))`

Answer (score 6):

Forget the loops, you want to use an aggregation function.  There's a recent discussion of them in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggregat).

```
with(data_old, tapply(yes, list(year, month), sum))
```

is one of many solutions.

Also, you don't need to use `c()` when you aren't concatenating anything.  Plain `1:12` is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a third option:

```
aggregate(yes ~ year + month, FUN=sum, data=data_old)
```

Comment: IMO, this is the way it should be done. It's clearer to the average programmer: we are aggregating, not "ddplying".

Comment: It's a good way to solve this problem, but my brain doesn't fit all of the options for other problems. The nice thing about plyr is that I just remember the pattern: split/operation/merge. ddply is the right function if I'm splitting a data.frame based on some columns and building a new data.frame on the results of an operation on the pieces.